# 100% memory consumption when running Jetbrains IDE for 5 min

Tags: memory, java, freeze

Fresh install of Arch Linux causes major memory leaks upon opening JAVA based applications, or Jet Brains applications to be exact.

Memory starts off fine but within 5 minutes its up over 90%, opening Jet Brains apps causes this to increase gradually, at 100% system freezes.

I'm running the LTS kernel as I figured it was more stable and robust (clearly not). I'm kind of at a dead end in terms of next steps.

free output periodically collected:

[image]

htop 5 minutes after app launch:

[image]

meminfo at 75% memory:

```
emTotal:       64953648 kB
MemFree:        14825820 kB
MemAvailable:   16159136 kB
Buffers:           98572 kB
Cached:         11348096 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          5834836 kB
Inactive:       10504840 kB
Active(anon):    4612836 kB
Inactive(anon):  9920788 kB
Active(file):    1222000 kB
Inactive(file):   584052 kB
Unevictable:         168 kB
Mlocked:             168 kB
SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
SwapFree:        4194300 kB
Zswap:                 0 kB
Zswapped:              0 kB
Dirty:               156 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4788644 kB
Mapped:          1026312 kB
Shmem:           9641700 kB
KReclaimable:     230328 kB
Slab:             550788 kB
SReclaimable:     230328 kB
SUnreclaim:       320460 kB
KernelStack:       18528 kB
PageTables:        29776 kB
SecPageTables:         0 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    36671124 kB
Committed_AS:   17705504 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       91248 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            23168 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1966080 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:     67584 kB
FilePmdMapped:     67584 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:    33774880 kB
DirectMap2M:    20897792 kB
DirectMap1G:    12582912 kB
```

Running: `for i in $(mount | grep ^tmpfs | awk {"print \$3"} ); do sudo du -sh ${i} 2>/dev/null; done`

Gives:

```
4.0K    /dev/shm
40K /tmp
40K /run/user/1000
```

What have I tried?

1. Setting Xmx4096m (no avail)
2. Downgrading the Jet Brains application (no difference)
3. Using openjdk over embedded runtime (no difference)
4. Using stable kernel (no difference)

Comment: Next time, please don't [delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757305/100-memory-consumption-when-running-jetbrains-ide-for-5-min) your question, and post it anew with further information; instead, *edit* it to add that information. Thanks!

Comment: can you run `htop` as root? I don't know why, but we're not seeing anywhere close to the userland memory usage that the system claims it has when looking at these processes. Also, is your jetbrains IDE perhaps indexing a large code base? Is it on the NTFS volume you're mounting?

Comment: @MarcusMüller htop as root still doesn't show any process exceeding 1% memory usage, probably because its a memory leak. It isn't indexing anything, its sat on the landing page.

Comment: well, if it's a memory leak in userland software, that would still appear as memory consumed by the specific piece of userland software leaking memory.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure well all I can say is nothing gets reported, even running as root. I get its hard to believe but that's the fact of the matter.

Comment: don't worry, I believe you! this is really an interesting puzzle. I'd try to do error isolation! This is a slim hope, but: Would it be possible to try this without mounting /dev/nvme1n1p1 ? Memory (erroneously) being used as userland/kernel buffer for FUSE purposes would be one way I could think of that our userland uses memory, without it being attributed to a process.